# Measure functions and functions defined starting with a measure

Tags: measure-theory

Any help with itens (b) and (c) of following question?
The (a) item is ok (or almost), in fact, I don't see where use the fact that the space is $\sigma$-finite.

> Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $f\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ a measurable function. Show that:
>
> (a) The function $g\colon[0,+\infty]\to[0,+\infty]$ such that $$g(\lambda):=\mu(\{x;|f(x)|>\lambda\})$$ is non-increasing and right-continuous.
>
> (b) If $f,f_1,f_2\ge0$ are measurable functions and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\ge0$ are constants such that $f\le\alpha_1 f_1+\alpha_2 f_2$, then $$\mu(\{x;f(x)>(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)\lambda\})\le\mu(\{x;|f_1(x)|>\lambda\})+\mu(\{x;|f_2(x)|>\lambda\}).$$
>
> (c) If $\{f_n\}$ is an increasing sequence of measurable functions and $f(x)=\lim f_n(x)$ for each $x$, then for each $\lambda>0$ we have that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\{x;|f_n(x)|>\lambda\})=\mu(\{x;f(x)>\lambda\}).$$

Answer (score 1):

For (b), let's first consider the following simplification of the question: suppose that $A, A_{1}, A_{2}$ are measurable sets (i.e., are in ${\cal M}$).  What set-theoretic relationship between these sets-for example,
$$
A \subset (A_{1} \cup A_{2}),
$$
would imply
$$
\mu(A) \leq \mu(A_{1}) + \mu(A_{2})?
$$

For (c), what is the set-theoretic relationship between the sets
$$
f_{n} > \lambda
$$
and 
$$
f_{n+1} > \lambda?
$$